# Django unable to load media files from aws S3 in development server

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Media files are getting properly uploaded to aws s3 bucket, but don't render to the html page. Can anyone help me with this please? I couldn't find what's wrong.

### Error

If I click on the link of the image below error will show up.

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please 
use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
</Message>
<RequestId>C6FE9209F5DE6296</RequestId>
<HostId>
 ry5ZRPCWjDxcxsYzII8q+x6BVMzRRiqvU1kZYxA5OQd07ojkyaqGoAd/OI=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

### settings.py

variables settings are shown below.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRECT_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add

```
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
```

to make sure s3 is not using v2, which is not supported by all regions. My full settings for S3 are:

```
#AWS S3 settings
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', '')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "eu-central-1"
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
```

Comment: I have added my full settings, maybe it helps. You will need to change region_name to where your AWS S3 server is.

Comment: added the variables with your reference settings but not worked.

Comment: And have you checked that the environment variables are in your environment, both locally and remotely?

Comment: Yes, checked both are same.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error was bucket policiy was empty. I added the policy now it is working fine. policy shown below **(Note:I have given public access in the below policy that is not recomended most of the time)**.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "allow-file-download-stmt",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal":"*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::zen-blogs/*"
        }
    ]
}
```